How to fix NoSuchMethodError while using MockMVC.perform?
I have the following structure in my integeration tests using Mockito's mockMVC -
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;


MvcResult response = mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/routes/prices")
.param("param", "1")
.param("param2", "07")
.param("from", "AP")
.param("to", "TG")
.param("strict", "true"))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andReturn();

This block of code works just fine with
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

But when i switch to version 3.2.12 (which is mandatory for me because of another issue, I getting the following error -
Servlet Request processing failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.isMultipartRequestParsed()'

I am forced to upgrade parent version. How to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

When you get these kinds of errors it means you are probably mixing incompatible versions of frameworks or even including different versions of jars from a single framework. Add your full pom.xml to the question as I suspect you are trying to be smarter then the dependency management from the Spring BOot starter.
